DB COPY from one elastic pool to another and selecting db size
I would like to create a copy of a azure db and move to another elastic pool
I have this:
CREATE DATABASE dbname
AS COPY OF tasql.dbname
(SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL( name = elasticpool ));
But I want to also select or provide the size.
Found out while copying db's this way from SSMS it defaults to 32 gigs and the db is 2 gigs in size.
not sure if it will work by adding size but copying db works
